error running custom profiles in osrm (Open Source Routing Machine)
trying to run custom profile in osrm on docker but gives this error:
what(): lua: error: /opt/moto.lua:9: module 'lib/traffic_signal' not found:
no field package.preload['lib/traffic_signal']
no file '/opt/lib/traffic_signal.lua'
no file '/usr/local/share/lua/5.2/lib/traffic_signal.lua'
no file '/usr/local/share/lua/5.2/lib/traffic_signal/init.lua'
no file '/usr/local/lib/lua/5.2/lib/traffic_signal.lua'
no file '/usr/local/lib/lua/5.2/lib/traffic_signal/init.lua'
no file '/usr/share/lua/5.2/lib/traffic_signal.lua'
no file '/usr/share/lua/5.2/lib/traffic_signal/init.lua'
no file './lib/traffic_signal.lua'
no file '/usr/local/lib/lua/5.2/lib/traffic_signal.so'
no file '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/lua/5.2/lib/traffic_signal.so'
no file '/usr/lib/lua/5.2/lib/traffic_signal.so'
no file '/usr/local/lib/lua/5.2/loadall.so'
no file './lib/traffic_signal.so'

according to the error it does not recognize the listed dependencies but the dependencies were added as is
-- vehicle custom

api_version = 4

Set = require('lib/set')
Sequence = require('lib/sequence')
Handlers = require("lib/way_handlers")
Relations = require("lib/relations")
TrafficSignal = require("lib/traffic_signal")
find_access_tag = require("lib/access").find_access_tag
limit = require("lib/maxspeed").limit
Utils = require("lib/utils")
Measure = require("lib/measure")

The vehiclecustom.lua profile was copied to the container creating a dockerfile:
FROM osrm/osrm-backend

COPY vehiclecustom.lua/opt/carcustom.lua

These configuration steps were performed to run the vehiclecustom.lua profile
sudo docker run -t -v "${PWD}:/data" osrm/osrm-backend osrm-extract -p /opt/vehiclecustom.lua /data/north-eastern-zone-latest.osm.pbf
sudo docker run -t -v "${PWD}:/data" osrm/osrm-backend osrm-partition /data/north-eastern-zone-latest.osrm
sudo docker run -t -v "${PWD}:/data" osrm/osrm-backend osrm-customize /data/north-eastern-zone-latest.osrm
sudo docker run -d -p 5000:5000 --rm --name osrm -v "${PWD}:/data" osrm/osrm-backend osrm-routed --algorithm mld /data/north-eastern-zone-latest.osrm

also copied the car.lua profile from the official osrm repository renaming it to vehiclecustom.lua without modifying anything nor touching any code, the same process of passing the file to the container and configuring the docker as previously shown was done again and the same error occurred again, but when I run the default osrm profiles like car.lua it runs successfully
I would greatly appreciate it if someone could help;
